# How to reference properly when citations are grouped by sections

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, subdividing

I want to number and prefix my references in each section by the number of the section. However, I need to cite a reference from a section in another subsection, but my solution does not allow it. Indeed, the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}

@article{A1,
  keywords = {articles},
  title={First Paper},
  author={Green},
  journal={Journal 1}, 
  note={based on \cite{C2}},
  year={2014}
}

@article{A2,
  keywords = {articles},
  title={Second paper},
  author={Smith},
  journal={Journal 2}, 
  year={2013}
}

@article{C1,
  keywords = {conferences},
  title={First Communication},
  author={Jack},
  journal={Conference 1}, 
  year={2012}
}

@article{C2,
  keywords = {conferences},
  title={Second Communication},
  author={John},
    journal={Conference 2}, 
  year={2011}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  defernumbers=true,
  citestyle=numeric,
  refsection=section 
]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibsecnum{#1}}
\newrobustcmd{\mkbibsecnum}[1]{\thesection-#1\relax}

\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}
\section{Articles}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[
  title={Articles},
  heading=none,
  keyword=articles,
  resetnumbers=true 
]

\section{Conferences}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[
  title={Conferences},
  heading=none,
  keyword=conferences,
  resetnumbers=true 
]

\end{document}
```

produces (I use bold case where the problem is):

> 1 Articles
>
> [1-1] Green. “First Paper”. In: Journal 1 (2014). **based on [1-4]**
>
> [1-2] Smith. “Second paper”. In: Journal 2 (2013).
>
> 2 Conferences
>
> [2-1] Jack. “First Communication”. In: Conference 1 (2012).
>
> [2-2] John. “Second Communication”. In: Conference 2 (2011).

while I would like that the first line be :

> [1-1] Green. “First Paper”. In: Journal 1 (2014). **based on [2-2]**.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Note that `biblatex` is doing exactly what you have told it to do. You have added 4 references to section 1. You have chosen only to print those which contain the keyword `articles`. But there are still 4 references in this section and I take it that's what the `1-4` refers to. You cannot refer here to items in another reference section since the whole point of such sections is that the items are local. (Cf. `refsegment` which works differently.) I think you might be better served using a `bibfilter` but I am not sure how you could get the numbering you want.

Comment: If you know in advance the number of the sections, you can use `refsegment=section` as the option of `biblatex` and then in the option of the `\printbibliography` use `prefixnumbers=X` and `prefixnumbers=Y` are the numbers of the Articles and Conferences sections.

Comment: I agree that biblatex is doing what I told it to do. Thanks anyway for a quick comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an hack using latex crossref mechanism to define the labels of the bibliographic references.

The trick is to redefine how the bibliography is handled (using the facilities provided by `biblatex`). To redefine it we use `enumitem` that allows us to specify how the labels and the references are formatted. We also have to redefine `\cite` accordingly.

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  defernumbers=true,
  citestyle=numeric,
  refsegment=section 
]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  [\mkbibbrackets]
  {}
  {\ref{\thefield{entrykey}}}
  {\addcomma}
  {\iffieldundef{postnote}{}{\addcomma\addspace\printfield{postnote}}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\begin{enumerate}[label={[\thesection-\arabic*]},ref=\thesection-\arabic*]}
  {\end{enumerate}}
  {\item\label{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Articles}\label{sec:article}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[
  title={Articles},
  heading=none,
  keyword=articles,
  resetnumbers=true,
]

\section{Conferences}\label{sec:conf}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[
  title={Conferences},
  heading=none,
  keyword=conferences,
  resetnumbers=true,
]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for a very quick answer. This works perfectly.